# Conditionally print value based on the value of another key

Tags: json, jq

Here's some example JSON:

```
{
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "Name",
      "Value": "foo"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Type",
      "Value": "C"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to print the value of "Value" only when "Key" is "Type". So it should print out "C". This is what I have so far.

```
echo $MY_TAGS | jq 'if .Tags[].Key == "Type" then .Tags[].Value else empty end'
```

But it prints out:

"foo"
"C"

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Type") | .Value
```